# layout_gravity in LinearLayout not working as expected

Tags: android, layout-gravity

The output for the following `XML` code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- layout_gravity example -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:layout_graviy="center"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100px"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/purple_700"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/hello" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

The light purple area, has `android:layout_gravity="center"`, but is still appearing on the top of the outer `LinearLayout`. Isn't `android:layout_gravity="center"` supposed to position the `View` or `Layout` in the center of its parent layout? I cannot understand why that's not the case here, while the dark purple area which is a `TextView` is positioning itself correctly on the use of `android:layout_gravity="center"`.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, there's a **TYPO**, you've written `graviy` instead of `gravity` in the child `LinearLayout` fixing which will center this layout Horizontally.

Second, if you want to center this child `LinearLayout` vertically and Horizontally too, then no need of setting `android:layout_gravity` in this one, instead set `android:gravity="center"` in the root `LinearLayout`, it will make this centered vertically and Horizontally.